# Word 2016 VSTO Com add-in error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I have a Visual Studio 2013 VSTO Word add-in project that appears to work normally when out of visual studio. But when I install it and run a particular function, an error is generated. I added the try catch because Word seemed so suppress the error and quietly went along seemingly fine (though it didn't).

At my wits end with this one. I don't understand why it would run correctly out of Visual Studio but not as installed. Other previously written functionality appears to work fine.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FrRibbon.Support.AppStats.WriteRibbonUsage(String subApplication, String featureInvoked, String initials)

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Namespace Support

Public Module AppStats

    Public Sub WriteRibbonUsage(subApplication As String, featureInvoked As String, initials As String)

        Try
            Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FRAppStatsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
                Using command As New SqlCommand("InsertRibbonUsage", connection)
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("subApplication", subApplication))
                    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("featureInvoked", featureInvoked))
                    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("initials", initials))
                    connection.Open()
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range.Text = String.Concat(ex.Message, vbCrLf, ex.StackTrace, vbCrLf, ex.Source, vbCrLf, ex.InnerException)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
End Namespace

 Private Sub btnRemoveHyperlinks_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnRemoveHyperlinks.Click

    Support.AppStats.WriteRibbonUsage("Super Macro", "Remove Hyperlinks", Helpers.GetUserName())

    If Not Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Any(Function(c) c.Title = "Remove Hyperlinks") Then
        RemoveHyperlinksTaskPane = New CustomPane(RemoveHyperlinksControl, "Remove Hyperlinks", "removeHyperlinks", RemoveHyperlinksWindowList)
        RemoveHyperlinksTaskPane.Visibility(True, "right", 425)
        RemoveHyperlinksControl.PopulateHyperLinkListBox()
    Else
        RemoveHyperlinksTaskPane.Visibility(True, "right", 425)
        RemoveHyperlinksControl.PopulateHyperLinkListBox()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No, you dont get the error on the function declaration.  More likely where you use that method, but you dont show that

Comment: @Plutonix that was what ex.Stacktrace returned, not what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't until I added the connection string to the Application Settings, and referenced it as: My.Settings.MyConnectionStringName, did it work. I had previously just added it manually inside ConnectionStrings section of app.config.

I suspect this has something to do with the app.config being compiled as VSTOAddinName.dll.config, which might explain why it works in Visual Studio but not when *installed*.